# MongoDB Quick Start fails, keeps returning "null" on Terminal

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, backend, mongodb-atlas

- Hi, I am self-learning MongoDB (with Node.js). Totally new to programming.
- My first Node.js application doesn't return the MongoDB document like it supposed to.

What I want to achieve:

- To work with the native MongoDB driver, and to complete the quick start procedure on MongoDB website: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/quick-start/

What I have tried so far:

1. Installed node & npm correctly;
2. Installed MongoDB@4.8 correctly;
3. Initialized all these via Terminal;
4. Set up Atlas, obtained connection string.

Still, when I put template (obtained from MongoDB quick start tutorial) into my server.js file, entered "npx nodemon app.js" to test, it returns: "null".

Here's code I put into server.js: (all account & password typed in correctly)

```
    const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
    // const uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
    const uri = "mongodb+srv://<myClusterUsername>:<myPassword>@cluster0.fytvkcs.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
    const client = new MongoClient(uri);
    async function run() {
      try {
        const database = client.db('sample_mflix');
        const movies = database.collection('movies');
        // Query for a movie that has the title 'Back to the Future'
        const query = { title: 'Back to the Future' };
        const movie = await movies.findOne(query);
        console.log(movie);
      } finally {
        // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
        await client.close();
      }
    }
    run().catch(console.dir);
```

As you can see, I also tried uri: localhost:27017, but output stay still on my Terminal: "null".

According to MongoDB, it was supposed to return such online sample doc:

```
      {
      _id: ...,
      plot: 'A young man is accidentally sent 30 years into the past...',
      genres: [ 'Adventure', 'Comedy', 'Sci-Fi' ],
      ...
      title: 'Back to the Future',
      ...
      }
```

Your help would be appreciated! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should open the folder in visual studio code like this:

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).